# Laravel - Notifications Controller can't use method user()

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller, notifications

I'm trying to add notification system to my Laravel project. I' watched this video to understand the system : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDDUxqpNgSc

Notification table, model et controller are created. Also, i have created the view with Vue.JS and Pusher. It's work well !

However, in the notification controller, when i try to user Auth::user() method it's return null. I read somewhere it's because the middleware 'auth' is not already load when the controller is.

This is my NotificationsController file :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Notification;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Idea;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class NotificationsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    function get(){
        $notification = Auth::user()->unreadNotifications()->get();
        return $notification;
    }
    function read(Request $request){
        Auth::user()->unreadNotifications()->find($request->id)->markAsRead();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this ?
Thank's for your time !

Comment: The `Auth` method is not available in the constructor (because session middleware has not run yet), but  it is available in other methods. So in your case, you're just not logged in.

Comment: It's sure, i'm login (I see the user name in right corner) but nothing, auth return null

Comment: how do you setup the route?

Comment: This is the route for this controller :

`//Route for notif

Route::post('/notification/get','NotificationsController@get')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/notification/read','NotificationsController@read')->middleware('auth');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was not about the Auth::user (It's accessible). I just baldy defined the notifiable_type in my model. It was App\Idea, it should be App\User